# Usage of "he himself"

Tags: punctuation, pronouns

> The boy's innate goodness will withstand the challenges because unless *he himself* wants to turn evil, [...].

My teacher thinks that commas should set off the word "himself", but I disagree. Who is right, and why?

Comment: 'because unless'... what? Either the word "because" is unnecessary, or there needs to be more to the sentence.

Comment: [...] continues it

Comment: Not getting into "he himself", there should definitely be a comma after *because*: "unless he himself wants to turn evil" is interrupting the clause beginning with *because*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a comma would be wrong there.

*(Deletes justification on the basis of it being a rearrangement of "he wants himself to turn evil", which is wrong because "he himself wants Fred to turn evil" is just as valid a sentence.  At least I realised that before I posted.)*

"Himself" here is actually an intensifier rather than a reflexive pronoun (the [World Atlas of Language Structures](http://wals.info/feature/description/47) notes that they are often identical).  As such it very much belongs with the noun phrase it is intensifying ("He"), and splitting them with a comma would weaken that relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think commas are necessary here, but they could serve to emphasize that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve such doubts is the reference to English corpus:
http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/ - AmE, you need to sign up;
http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/ - BrE, you do not need to sign up.
By the way, your teacher was wrong, you don't have to put commas before and after himself:)